# Display all Archives

Tags: wordpress, jquery, wordpress-theming

I have create few posts in latest news section(CPT) and I want to show its all posts as archive of custom post type ,Its showing only of the July month archives so as for now I have published few posts in back dates (like I have posted it in May months) but the archives I am getting only of the july month.

How to get archives of the May months so that when I click on May(2013) then it should be shows all posts of May-2013?

And how to make sure I am not using category, it should be archive only?

Here is the function I am using to show the Archive:

```
<?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly', 'limit' => 12 ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are showing it monthly, you need you try yearly if you want to show more months.

`<?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'yearly') ); ?>`

There are more options to run on the `wp_get_archives();` such as `postbypost` that you can also try.

`<?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'postbypost') ); ?>`

Look at the codex to see what these other parameters can do for you.

**http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives**

Please also notice that I am removing the `limit` parameter so it defaults to "no limit"

Comment: Thanks for your effort! 
But its important to put all archives in month wise Can you please
try to figure it out why May months Archives are not working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

seems you don't have post in on may.
the following arguments are the default for the function **wp_get_archives**.

```
<?php $args = array(
    'show_count'            => 0,
    'hide_empty'            => 1,
    'type'          => 'monthly', 
    'limit'         => '',
    'format'        => 'html', 
    'before'        => '',
    'after'         => '', 
    'show_post_count'   => false,
    'echo'          => 1, 
    'order'         => 'DESC',

   ); ?>
```

as you see **hide_empty is 1**. if you change this to 0 (zero) the your may will be shown even you dont have post for May.